# Left align text in full width div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I am attempting to left align text in a div that takes the full width of it's parent.

This is the structure of one of several links created using Angular's Flex Layout.

```
<div class="container" fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="10px">
  <a mat-flat-button color="primary" fxFlex href="https://example.com/">
    <div class="hoverOff"><fa-icon [icon]="faToolbox"></fa-icon>Broken</div>
    <div class="hoverOn">
      <div class="text">
        Is your request causing an impact to a business-critical function, which is impacting daily production?
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  ......
</div>
```

Without hovering, the `.hoverOff` element is visible. During hover, the `.hoverOn` element slides over the `.hoverOff` element.

`.hoverOn` uses `position: absolute` to stay hidden until hover.

Adding `text-align: left` to `.text` left aligns the text like I want but it's on the left edge of the div and not in the center with margins like I would like.

I have created an [example for this](https://codesandbox.io/s/4zk5z32910?module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) and the CSS is below.

```
a {
  color: white !important;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

a .hoverOn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #00539b;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;

  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 99%; /* Prevents flicker on bottom corners  */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Centers div for new width  */
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1); /* Material's Standard easing */
}

.text {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

a:hover .hoverOn {
  height: 100%;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please show the css in the question too: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just specify the additional padding in `.text`?